# How to delete a method in ATL COM C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, atl

I am working on visual studio c++ 6 , developing a COM/dll. I created a STDMethod and deleted it through the interface(Right click and deleted). Now everytime I build the code it pops a window with a message " This file has been modified outside of the source editor.do you want to reload it?" Please suggest me a way to avoid this problem.Thanks

Comment: Do a full recompile.  Make sure your system clock is set correctly.

Comment: I don't know if it's any consolation, but it's the same in VS 2010. The annoying part is that the file isn't even open in the editor, at least as far as you can tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be deleting the method from the IDL file.

Each time the IDL is recompiled the project .h file will be rebuilt. if it is open in your editor you will receive this notification. close the .h file editor window if it is open before the IDL is recompiled.

Btw, The same is true for dlldata.c, prjname_i.c, and prjname_p.c for the proxy/stub code files.